# globalization in web.config missing after publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config

I am publishing my site to azure which all seems to be working just fine, appart from the published version of the web.config is missing the

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

All my app keys have all published fine. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which execution model are you using: cloud app or web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check to see if you have a transformation in the release/publish config file that might be removing this item?

You probably have something in web.Publish.config.

**NOTE:** You'll need to have 'Show all files' turned on to see the transformation files.

Comment: I had looked at that as i user the Web.Release.config for replacing my connection string but I have no reference to globalization in the Web.Release.config file. I would have though that it would just straight copy whats in my Web.config.